Avalonia UI Music Store App tutorial - dialog not opening on button click
I'm currently trying to learn Avalonia by following the music store app tutorial;
I'm currently stuck at this step : https://docs.avaloniaui.net/docs/tutorials/music-store-app/opening-a-dialog
For some reason, the window doesn't seem to open when I click on the button.
I first noticed that my Avalonia packages were not up to date, so I updated it hoping it would solve the issue, but it doesn't seem to have any effect.
I added a debug line to write in the console when I click the button, to be sure the event was triggered, and it does indeed seem to trigger. However, still no new window poping up.
Here is my code so far :
MainWindowViewModel.cs :
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace Avalonia.MusicStore.ViewModels;

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        ShowDialog = new Interaction<MusicStoreViewModel, AlbumViewModel?>();
        BuyMusicCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create((() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Open dialog");
            MusicStoreViewModel store = new MusicStoreViewModel();
            IObservable<AlbumViewModel?> result = ShowDialog.Handle(store);
        }));
    }
    
    public ICommand BuyMusicCommand { get; }
    
    public Interaction<MusicStoreViewModel, AlbumViewModel?> ShowDialog { get; }
}

MainWindow.axaml :
<Window xmlns="https://github.com/avaloniaui"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="using:Avalonia.MusicStore.ViewModels"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="800" d:DesignHeight="450"
        x:Class="Avalonia.MusicStore.Views.MainWindow"
        x:DataType="vm:MainWindowViewModel"
        Icon="/Assets/avalonia-logo.ico"
        Title="Avalonia.MusicStore"
        TransparencyLevelHint="AcrylicBlur"
        Background="Transparent"
        ExtendClientAreaToDecorationsHint="True"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

        <Panel>
            <ExperimentalAcrylicBorder IsHitTestVisible="False">
                <ExperimentalAcrylicBorder.Material>
                    <ExperimentalAcrylicMaterial
                        BackgroundSource="Digger"
                        TintColor="Black"
                        TintOpacity="1"
                        MaterialOpacity="0.65" />
                </ExperimentalAcrylicBorder.Material>
            </ExperimentalAcrylicBorder>
            
            <Panel Margin="40">
                <Button HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Command="{Binding BuyMusicCommand}">
                    <PathIcon Data="{StaticResource store_microsoft_regular}"/>
                </Button>
            </Panel>
            
        </Panel>

</Window>

MainWindow.axaml.cs :
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Avalonia.MusicStore.ViewModels;
using Avalonia.ReactiveUI;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace Avalonia.MusicStore.Views;

public partial class MainWindow : ReactiveWindow<MainWindowViewModel>
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenActivated(action => action(ViewModel!.ShowDialog.RegisterHandler(DoShowDialogAsync)));
    }

    private async Task DoShowDialogAsync(IInteractionContext<MusicStoreViewModel, AlbumViewModel?> interaction)
    {
        MusicStoreWindow dialog = new MusicStoreWindow();
        dialog.DataContext = interaction.Input;
        
        AlbumViewModel? result = await dialog.ShowDialog<AlbumViewModel?>(this);
        interaction.SetOutput(result);
    }
}

I feel like I may have missed a step or something, but I can't figure out where.
